# Find game which a Steam profile background is from?

Tags: steam, game-identification

How do I see which game a Steam background is from?

For example this background image:
http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/items/620/904c34bd20f5a5f5eadb074cce42d2606b266acc.jpg

[image: Portal 2 background]

Comment: I was just listening to Portal 2 soundtrack yesterday with [this cover image](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110525201930/half-life/en/images/f/f7/P2songstotestbyv1cover.jpg).

Answer (score 33):

The easier way is to look at the game ID:

> [http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/items/**620**/904c34bd20f5a5f5eadb074cce42d2606b266acc.jpg](http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/items/620/904c34bd20f5a5f5eadb074cce42d2606b266acc.jpg)

If you put that number into this url, you go to the game page:

> [http://store.steampowered.com/app/**620**/](http://store.steampowered.com/app/620/)

Game 620 on steam is Portal 2.

Keavon also suggested searching for the appid on http://steamdb.info/, which seems to work quite well.

Comment: This may not work for all backgrounds because it's possible the appid doesn't have a store page. However, searching for the appid on steamdb.info will tell you what the appid title is.

Comment: That is an incredible answer! Why the hell didn't I remember game ids >_<

Answer (score 16):

Adding onto [GnomeSlice's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/158302/57720) for a sure-fire way to find it:

Right click the user's profile in a browser and click *View Background Image*. Copy this image's URL and do a Google Images search by image for the background's URL...
[image]

Then remove any text from the search, but not the image, and add `site:steamcardexchange.net` to the search...
[image]

This should show you the result on Steam Card Exchange's website for the game with that background...
[image]

That page is the showcase for all things related to Trading Cards and the game with the background. This should work for pretty much any background, no matter how obscure it is.

Answer (score 14):

If you're using chrome, you can right-click the image and select 'Search Google for this image".

That particular background is from Portal 2.